# Subir archivo de excel python - Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

al leer un archivo de Excel con pandas al ingresar los datos en el dataframe me excluye un valor de la celda, por ejemplo en la celda esta este valor 05001123456 y al ingresar el valor al dataset aparece 5001123456 que puede ser eso. Muchas gracias

---

este es el codigo:

```
   def Procesar(self):
    fila = 4
    hoja = 'RD_Unificado_Datos'
    archivo = str(self.archivo.get())

    df = pd.read_excel(io = archivo, sheet_name = hoja, header = fila, names=None, index_col=None,
        engine = 'openpyxl', dtype={'CO': str})
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

    print(len(df.axes[1])) ##Numero columnas
    print(len(df.axes[0])) ##Numero filas
    print('----------')
    
    columnas = len(df.axes[1])
    filas = len(df.axes[0])

    Modulos.conexionBBDD()
    Modulos.eliminar("datos")

    lista =[]
    for f in range(filas):
        for c in range(columnas):
            valor= df.iloc[f, c]
            lista.append(valor)

        Modulos.insertar(lista, "datos")
        lista.clear()

    messagebox.showinfo("RDV", "Proceso realizado con exito")
```

Las celda de excel tiene valores como 050011234567, 050011234568, 050011234569

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Al usar pandas para traer los datos de Excel, en una columna que tiene el valor 05001123456 lo que me aparece en el dataset es 5001123456, quisiera saber porque me elimina el cero del principio, la celda en Excel está como texto.

Comment: Debes colocar el código que presenta el error y por lo menos un ejemplo reproducible para ver tu trabajo y poder brindarte una posible ayuda.